# Make list from source code of page

Tags: php, jquery

I have page with this part in the source code:

```
<ul class="videos-list listaaa">
<li class="active" topic="5530" video="4072">
<i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
שאלה אחת
</li>
<li topic-id="5530" video="4073">
<i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
שאלה טוב
</li>
<li topic-id="5530" video="4074">
<i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
למה לי
</li>
<li topic-id="5530" video="4075">
<i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
אבא בננה
</li>
<li topic-id="5530" video="4076">
<i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
לרוץ מהר
</li>
<li topic-id="5530" video="4077">
<i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
סיכום
</li>
</ul>
```

How I can to print list of only titles and video value like:

```
שאלה אחת-4072
שאלה טוב-4073
למה לי-4074
אבא בננה-4075
לרוץ מהר-4076
סיכום-4077
```

I try using jquery, but not success (I'm not get the video attr) so I try with php...
my code:

```
$('ul.videos-list li').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('video') + '-' + $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text());
});
```

thank you

Comment: These are not valid HTML attributes, so depending on what browser is used it might just suppress them. If your own PHP script is generating this output, then make them custom data attributes (`data-video`, `data-topic`, etc.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to take text from source code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953403/how-to-take-text-from-source-code)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Here's a solution without the need of opening the console:

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('li');
for (var i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {

    var b = (a[i].getAttribute('video') + ' - ' + a[i].innerHTML.replace('<i class="fa fa-circle"></i>','').replace('\n',''));

    a[i].innerHTML = b;

}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/b568bbn4/)

You can try it with javascript:

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('li');
for (var i = 0; i<a.length; i++) {

    console.log(a[i].getAttribute('video') + ' - ' + a[i].innerHTML.replace('<i class="fa fa-circle"></i>','').replace('\n',''));
}
```

```html
<ul class="videos-list listaaa">
<li class="active" topic="5530" video="4072">
<i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
שאלה אחת
</li>
<li topic-id="5530" video="4073">
<i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
שאלה טוב
</li>
<li topic-id="5530" video="4074">
<i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
למה לי
</li>
<li topic-id="5530" video="4075">
<i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
אבא בננה
</li>
<li topic-id="5530" video="4076">
<i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
לרוץ מהר
</li>
<li topic-id="5530" video="4077">
<i class="fa fa-circle"></i>
סיכום
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: sure it does, did you open your console to see it?

Comment: but I must to show only what in videos-list listaaa class, if not, I get more texts from the page...